# How Get data from a derived class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, class, inheritance

Get data from a derived class.. 
My samples.

```
public class Maintest
{
    public string name = "2";
}

public class test : Maintest
{
    string bla = name;
}
```

or

```
public class test : Maintest
{
    test child = new test();
    string bla = child.name;
}
```

Please reply
or
Share a link to explore

For example there is the main class
and I have a derived class that will output data of the first class.
As an example, I just wanted to pass the value of the derivative in the main class. For a proper understanding

Comment: Where are you want get data? In method or constructor?

Comment: For example there is the main class
and I have a derived class that will output data of the first class.
As an example, I just wanted to pass the value of the derivative in the main class. For a proper understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the field from a property, it might look a little something like this.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        Console.WriteLine(test.greeting);
    }
}

// make this abstract if you're never directly instantiate MainTest
public abstract class MainTest
{
    public string name = "world";
}

public class Test  : MainTest
{
    public string greeting {get { return "Hello " + name;}}
}
```

http://dotnetfiddle.net/R8kwh3

Also, you can enforce a contract by doing something like

```
public abstract class MainTest
{
    public string name = "world";
    // create an abstract property to ensure it gets implemented in the inheriting class
    public abstract string greeting {get; private set;}
}

public class Test  : MainTest
{
    public override string greeting {get { return "Hello " + name;}}
}
```

Comment: Thx you first variant is approached.The second is not understood as not yet learned the abstract classes and override - type.

Comment: @lails an abstract class is to be inherited and never instantiated. An abstract property declaration does not provide an implementation of the property accessors -- it declares that the class supports properties, but leaves the accessor implementation to derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want get data in method? Therefore, you can use this:

```
public class test : Maintest
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```